# How to print Reference count for debug purpose on android?

Tags: android

I have limit knowledge of `Refbase`, `sp`, `wp` of android. As far as I know if the `refcount` of one `sp`(strong point) decreased to 0, then the object wrapped in `sp` would be deleted.

Now I want to debug a snippet of codes from android `AOSP`, it looks like:

```
void OMXClient::disconnect() {
    ALOGI("[Alan] OMXClient::disconnect!!!");
    if (mOMX.get() != NULL) {
        ALOGI("[Alan] will mOMX.clear() !!!");
        mOMX.clear();
        mOMX = NULL;
    }
}
```

I want to print the `refCount` of `mOMX` every time before `mOMX.clear()`.

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: you sure you do not want to add more tags?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Could you please be more specifical ?